# Why did the the data that should be deleted from the time interval sql statement still in the Apache IoTDB database?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I encountered a strange situation online. I executed sql `delete from root.hess.running.inverter.WL000001.WL2N1N10131001D9S1000008.* where time < 2024-01-16T10:10:32 and deleted the time before 2024-01-16T10:10:32` in Apache IoTDB. Then today I found that part of the data before 2024-01-16T10:10:32 is still in the database. I consumed the data again. The relevant data has not been reissued. All data has only been sent once. It should not be the case that it was deleted and then re-written. Is there a scenario where the deletion of data in IoTDB is not complete after deletion? Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems should have been fixed in version 1.3.0 of Apache IoTDB. It is best to upgrade to the latest version (which should be version 1.3.1 now).